# Is there a way to store and use SSH key on TeamCity?

Tags: maven, ssh, teamcity, keystore

I have some test which is run by TeamCity using Maven. This test connects to some host using SSH key provided. For some reasons I cannot store the SSH key in the source code of the test.

When I run this test locally its ok: I can store the key in any place of my local drive and pass a link to it to the test.

The question is how can I do same trick when test is run on TeamCity.

I know TeamCity has some storage for SSH keys. But how my test can connect to that storage and fetch a key from it? 
Which path should I use?
Or, may be, I should put a key on some folder inside the host which runs TeamCity and provide a link to that folder to my test?

What is the best practise for this task?